# Combo not going any higher than 1, trying to make combat system (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a combat system and obviously need a combo variable to keep track of what current combo i am in

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.M1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Mouse)
    print("Received M1 from the Client")
    local combo = 0
    local startTime = tick()

    if combo == 3 then
        print("M1 Combo!")
        combo = 0
    end

    if tick() - startTime >= 2 then
        combo = 0
    end

    combo = combo + 1
    print(combo)
end)
```

But it just seems to never go higher than 1 or never add 1 to the combo

I've tried adding print debugs to the scripts (as seen under combo = combo + 1), but none of those really helped, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combo` is declared as a local variable inside the event handler, so every time it receives an event, it starts `combo` at 0. Instead, `combo` and `startTime` should be declared outside of the function.

Some other small things are that `tick()` [will be deprecated soon](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/luau-recap-june-2020/632346) so `os.time()` should be used instead. Additionally, `combo = combo + 1` can be shortened to `combo += 1`, and `game:GetService("{serviceName}")` is [recommended](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/gameplayers-vs-gamegetserviceplayers-whats-the-difference/334593/7) over `game.{serviceName}`. Below, `lastHit` is used instead of `startTime` since it tracks the time of the last hit.

The script after all these fixes:

```lua
local combo = 0
local lastHit = os.time()

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Remotes.M1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Mouse)
    print("Received M1 from the Client")
    combo += 1

    if os.time() - lastHit >= 2 then
        combo = 0
    end

    lastHit = os.time()

    if combo == 3 then
        print("M1 Combo!")
        combo = 0
    end

    print(combo)
end)
```